# Multiplying multidimensional arrays by one dimensional arrays Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I want to do matrix multiplication with my function that takes 2 matrixs as parameters. My code works for all the test cases except 
`mul([0, 1, 2],[[0], [1], [2]])= [0, 1, 4]`
which should = [5]. Any idea why?

```
            rows_A = get_rowCount(A)
            cols_A = get_columnCount(A)
            rows_B = get_rowCount(B)
            cols_B = get_columnCount(B)

            if cols_A != rows_B:
                return 'Error(mul): size mismatch'


            if isinstance(A[0],list) == False: 
                # if one is 1d and other is 2d:
                if isinstance(B[0], list):
                    new_list = []
                    for i in B:
                        new_list.append(i[0])
                    B = new_list 
                return [a*b for a,b in zip(A,B)]


            # Create the result matrix
            # Dimensions would be rows_A x cols_B
            C = [[0 for row in range(cols_B)] for col in range(rows_A)]

            for i in range(rows_A):
                for j in range(cols_B):
                    for k in range(cols_A):
                        C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
            return C
```

Comment: Did you try printing relevant data in the loop(s) to see what was happening?

Comment: Have you tested the `1d/2d` conditional statements/suites? Do they work as expected? Examined by printing values?

Comment: i tried putting it into 2 one dimensional arrays, isn't that the same logic as if it both came in a 1D array in the first place?

Comment: I can simply add the values in my current output array to get the desired output of [5] but I'm confused on how my logic is wrong that it doesn't just return [5] after multiplication

Comment: Your example looks like a *partial* function definition can you edit it so that it is complete. You also haven't shown `get_rowCount` or `get_columnCount`. Please [edit] to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are passing `[0, 1, 2]` for `A` - you should be passing `[[0, 1, 2]]`.